# Ember Data creates local record on GET that returns 404

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, http-status-code-404

When I request a single resource that returns a 404 (or 403 for that matter) Ember Data is creating a local record.

For example, I load my app from scratch at `/items/123`. The adapter does a request for `GET /items/123` which results in a 404 but now I have an `item` record in my local store with `id=123`. All attributes are `undefined` expect where the model defines default values.

Also, all model flags are `false` except `isValid` which is `true`.

Is this excepted behaviour? It seems strange that the local record gets created even though the server is saying that it doesn't exist (or that the user is not allowed to see it).

### Details

I'm running Ember *1.8.1* and Ember Data *1.0.0-beta.11*.

Here's what I have for Routes—pretty basic stuff:

```
// itemsRoute, TOP LEVEL
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('item');
}


// itemRoute, CHILD LEVEL
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.find('item', params.item_id); // <-- this returns 404
},
actions: {
    error: function(err) {
      this.replaceWith('items'); // jump out to main list view
      return true; // ensure error bubbles up
    }
}
```

The rejection in the `model` hook is working because the `error` action is triggered and I'm redirected out the top level `/items` view. But I still end up with a local record for an `item` that doesn't exist.

Comment: I haven't seen this happen.  Are you sure the server is actually returning 404?  Asking on the off chance that it's responding with some sort of custom "404" implementation but actually returning 200 in the header.  If not, can you provide some code example to help better understand the behavior?

Comment: Server is returning a proper 404 code (screenshot: http://cl.ly/Yq8W). I've added some code snippets from my Routes...it's pretty basic stuff I think.

Comment: It seems a little weird to me.  I'm wondering it replaceWith() is behaving differently than we're assuming it does.  I haven't been able to replicate this the phantom null record due to a failure, but if nothing else works you could consider overriding the ajaxSuccess and/or ajaxError method for the adapter.

Comment: Strange indeed. I have been able to catch the error in `ajaxError` in the adapter but I haven't followed through on that approach yet.

Comment: This is a little uglier.  You could also override the afterModel [aftermodel(model, transition)] method and do a reload on the model in the instance that the transition reveals a 404.  It's not very elegant though.  Hrm... is there a reason the server is returning a 404 error as opposed to an empty data set or JSON response with error property?

Comment: In your toplevel itemsRoute an array controller with sortProperties and sortAscending property set may be a more "ember way" of doing it.  I don't know if this is possibly somehow related to the issue you're seeing but I noticed you're sorting the array on the success call back of the promise.  It reminded me of a similar situation I ran into and when I first tried to use the same approach, I had some weird ember data issues I don't remember the specifics of.  Anyway https://github.com/KraftyKai/EmberBlog/blob/master/app/controllers/posts-list.js was my solution.  Maybe it'll reveal something.

Comment: I've removed the sorting from the code snippet—it has no affect on the the local record being created.

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas.  I've replicated the parts of your code I see here and threw some 404 errors from my server but... I haven't been able to reproduce a phantom record problem.  If you figure out what it was definitely leave a comment here.  I'll keep an eye on the thread too in case you put any updates.  Good luck!

Comment: Will do. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a little more... try altering your error handler in itemRoute from...

```
actions: {
    error: function(err) {
      this.replaceWith('items'); // jump out to main list view
      return true; // ensure error bubbles up
    }
}
```

to...

```
actions: {
    error: function(err) {
        this.transitionTo('items');  // jump out to main list view
        return false;  // Stop event bubbling - we've handled it.
        //You could also console.log parts or all of your error

        //You can return true too if you want to keep the event bubbling.
    }
}
```

I don't have a concrete reason for why this would be yet.  Waiting to hear back from you if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing from `replaceWith` to `transitionTo` and not returning `true` has no affect on the record being created in the store. It's still created.

Comment: Another thought is to try to provide the promise you are creating when making the call to store.find() with pass/fail callbacks.  IE, this.store.find('item', param).then(successFunction, failFunction);

Comment: `store.find` already returns a Promise though... Shouldn't the 404 response trigger a rejected promise on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a bug. It seems this was fixed a while back but as was reintroduced by a change on March 14.

I've submitted a bug report https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3085